# Subdomain not working with Nginx virtual host

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have setup subdomain virtual host but its not working getting 522 error.
main domain is working fine. I have also check nginx error log but its not showing any error.

Envirnment
Ubantu 18.10

I have already setup DNS and also check nginx error log but don't see any nginx errors.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name subdomain.com www.subdomain.com;
root /var/www/html/subdomain.com/public_html;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; 
index index.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

anyone please suggest possible solution to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Pardon me if i sound totally noob here but `subdomain.domain.com` Isn't this how a subdomain is written? `subdomain.com` will look for "subdomain" as main domain.

Comment: Yes main domain is IE  maindomain.com
and subdomain = subdomain.maindomain.com

I have just add subdomain.com just for example.

Comment: 522 is a status code used by cloudflare to indicate that it could not negotiate a connection to your server. So your server's error log will not have any information, as the request probably never reached it. You need to look at your cloudflare configuration.

Comment: Yes I have setupDNS  properly in cloudflare. other subdomain with apache configuration is working fine.